# IndexError: list index out of range peek opeartion for stack in python

Tags: python, list, class, stack

```
class stack():
    def __init__(self):
        self.s=[]
    def push(self,x):
        self.s.append(x)
    def pop(self):
        if self.s==[]:
            return -1
        else:
            return self.s.pop()
    def peek(self):
        return self.s[-1]
    def isempty(s):
        return len(s)
    def size(self):
        return len(self.s)
def printNGE(arr):
    v=[]
    n=len(arr)
    s=stack()
    for i in range(n):
        if s.size()==0:
            v.append(-1)
        elif s.size()>0 and s.peek()>arr[i]:
            v.append(s.peek())
        elif s.size()>0 and s.peek()<=arr[i]:
            while(s.size()>0 and s.peek()<=arr[i]):
                s.pop()
            if s.size==0:
                v.append(-1)
            else:
                v.append(s.peek())
        s.push(arr[i])
        print('s z',s.peek(),s.size())
    return v
arr=[1,3,2,4]
x=printNGE(arr)
print(x)
```

I am trying to implement greatest integer to the left in python using stack, I am getting an eror , the code worked fine for greatest int to the left if you change the loop for(n-1,-1,-1)

```
File "c:\Users\Amit\Desktop\greatrightstak.py", line 42, in <module>
    x=printNGE(arr)
 File "c:\Users\Amit\Desktop\greatrightstak.py", line 35, in printNGE
    v.append(s.peek())
 File "c:\Users\Amit\Desktop\greatrightstak.py", line 13, in peek
    return self.s[-1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have a small error with missing brackets:

```
if s.size==0:
```

should be

```
if s.size()==0:
```